# jQuery accessing updated values from variables on different events

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have a function which copies the values of a group of inputs to another group of inputs if the user clicks a button.

The function works fine but I'm having trouble with the vars I'm using to get the information. I want to use global variables because I want to use the same variables later on but it only works when I wrap those vars inside the function.

I've posted the two scenarios where it's working and not working below. Can anyone explain why I cannot access the correct value at that given time using a global variable?

**EDITS:** The 3 elements #admin-name, #admin-email and #admin-number are all present in the DOM when the script is called, as I am doing everything with document ready. I understand that when the script first runs these values will be blank because they haven't been filled out by the user yet. What I don't understand is why can't jQuery get the value once it has been filled out and I call the variable on the click function.

**Not Working**

```
var contactName = $('#contact-name').val();
var contactEmail = $('#contact-email').val();
var contactNumber = $('#contact-number').val();

$(".step-two .copy-details").on('click', function(){
    $('#admin-name').val(contactName);
    $('#admin-email').val(contactEmail);
    $('#admin-number').val(contactNumber);
  });
```

**Working**

```
$(".step-two .copy-details").on('click', function(){
    var contactName = $('#contact-name').val();
    var contactEmail = $('#contact-email').val();
    var contactNumber = $('#contact-number').val();
    $('#admin-name').val(contactName);
    $('#admin-email').val(contactEmail);
    $('#admin-number').val(contactNumber);
  });
```

Comment: "*I understand that when the script first runs these values will be blank because they haven't been filled out by the user yet*". That's it. Your variables contain empty strings. jQuery does not magically get you live values when referring to strings. You'll have to tell it to do that.

Comment: :( if only jQuery worked this way. Life would be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man I struggled with this one, this post helped flesh it out for me, [jQuery Global Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389062/jquery-global-variable). The problem is the variable called in the click function was still getting the original value of 0. To make the variable update when a new value is added you need to declare it and then wrap it in a change function like so:

**JS**

```
// declare the variable
var contactName;

// wrap it in a change function so the value updates
$('#contact-name').on('change', function(){
    contactName = $('#contact-name').val();
});

// use the variable inside the function and it will show the updated value
$('.step-two').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $('#admin-name').val(contactName);
    console.log('contactName = ' + contactName);
});
```